# bottom property becomes wrong after dynamic DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="body">
    Some text
    <div style="display:none;">Very long text</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="copyBody(this);">More</button>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
function copyBody(elem){
    elem.parentElement.innerText = elem.parentElement.children[0].innerText;
}
```

When I click the button, the invisible text is correctly copied to the body div, any subsequent html content that doesn't have absolute positioning is moved correctly.

The problem is that I have a sticky footer, with this style:

```
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```

The definition of bottom property states:

> Definition and Usage
>
> For absolutely positioned elements, the bottom
> property sets the bottom edge of an element to a unit above/below the
> bottom edge of its containing element.

The problem is that the footer remains exactly in the same position. How to make it recalculate the containing element edge?

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejdzkf35/2/) working on Chrome

Comment: a fiddle will help over here to visualize your problem

Comment: Where is your footer?

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: At page load footer is on the very bottom of the page. After DOM manipulation the window grows and the footer remains at the same position. There are no errors...

Comment: `position: fixed` what your looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML looks kinda confusing, try to avoid using `.body` class.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 40px; // footer height
}
```

Set position to relative on .container. Your footer is positioned absolute so it needs some related element. Also I did remove the `.container` class by your footer wrapping div.

```
<div class="footer"><div>Footer</div></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ejdzkf35/4/)**

**EDIT:** Added padding-bottom so your footer is not overlapping content.